# What are Docker COPY's rules about symlinks / how can I preserve symlinks?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, copy, symlink

From this trial, it looks like Docker's `COPY` command doesn't preserve symlinks -- rather, it "follows" symlinks and copies the target file(?):

```
$ ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user domain users  1 Mar 26 09:37 a -> b
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users  0 Mar 26 09:37 b
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user domain users  1 Mar 26 09:41 c -> d
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users  0 Mar 26 09:41 d
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users 54 Mar 26 09:39 Dockerfile
$
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.7 as base

COPY [ "./*", "/foo/bar/" ]
```

```
$ docker build -t foo:tmp . && docker run -it foo:tmp
[+] Building 1.1s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 116B                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.7                                                              0.8s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 12.52kB                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.7@sha256:8421d9a84432575381bfabd248f1eb56f3aa21d9d7cd2511583c68c9b7511d10 0.0s
 => [2/2] COPY [ ./*, /foo/bar/ ]                                                                                          0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                     0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:81531080243eedcb443c7fe0c9e85df92515a6cf3f997c549414cae9bf6ca925                               0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/foo:tmp                                                                                 0.0s
/ # ls -l /foo/bar/
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            67 Mar 26 16:43 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 26 16:37 a
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 26 16:37 b
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 26 16:41 c
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 26 16:41 d
/ #
```

This behavior appears to be the same whether I'm copying from my context or from another Docker image layer.

**Is there some way I can get Docker copy to preserve symlinks** i.e. instead of it "following" them and creating hard files? Or is there some convention to work around this situation?

The context behind this question is that a base layer I'm copying from has (a lot of) a mix of files and symlinks that point to them. Example: `libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.1 -> libfoo.so.1.0.0`

---

I spent a while searching online for this topic, but found surprisingly few hits. Most "close" questions were about symlinks to directories, which isn't the same as my situation. The closest hit I got was this unfortunately unanswered question: https://forums.docker.com/t/copying-symlinks-into-image/39521

Comment: Does copying the directory `COPY ./ /foo/bar/` work better than copying individual files/symlinks?  (This would be consistent with `/bin/cp`; it's not well-documented in the [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).)

Comment: @DavidMaze - that does work; thank you. At first, I thought my real-world case would be trickier to do this than my MCVE because the source and destination directory structures are different...but it didn't matter: as long as I specify the *full* source path (ending in `/`) and the *full* destination path, this works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works if you try to copy the entire directory as a unit, rather than trying to copy the files in the directory:

```sh
COPY ./ /foo/bar/
```

Note that there are some subtleties around copying directories: the [Dockerfile `COPY` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) notes that, if you `COPY` a directory,

> NOTE: The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.

This is fine for your case where you're trying to copy the entire build context.  If you have a subdirectory you're trying to copy, you need to make sure the subdirectory name is also on the right-hand side of `COPY` and that the directory name ends with `/`.

Comment: Can you help explain why `COPY foo foo` is different than `COPY foo/ foo/` in this context?

Comment: The `/` at the end of the destination name is syntactically significant.

Comment: Can you explain how Docker's compile process will behave differently given the presence or absence of `/`?